# AVPlayer fast forwards unexpectedly

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I'm playing a video using `AVPlayer` in a modal. When I swipe down the view, video play continues like `Youtube` app and I can hear the sound. But the problem is when I bring the view back, player plays the part of video that was not displayed very quickly until it catches up to current cursor.

For example, if I hid the view at `1:00` and revives it at `1:30`, player shows the part from `1:00 to 1:30` in very high rate. I want video to be just playing at `1:30` cursor smoothly.

Comment: Have to tried any code so far?

Answer (score 0):

When hiding the `view`, you need to `pause()` the `player`, i.e.

```
player.pause()
```

Now, when you need to unhide the `view`, call `play()` method on the `player`, i.e.

```
player.play()
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Pausing is not what I intend though, I want the video to keep playing in background in a similar way with Youtube.

Comment: Youtube video doesn't play in the background.